# How do I delete sample app from an android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Somehow, I have deleted the code for the sample apps from the workspace, but the apps still show up in the android emulator. How do I delete them?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Inside the emulator go to the Settings app, then Applications -> Manage Applications -- you can delete them from there.

Comment: In newer versions of the simulator, you'll have to click and hold on the app. Then while still holding it, drag it to the top right where the text "Uninstall" will show up.

Comment: What Dyba said above, in the main application list screen.

Comment: Settings app, then Applications -> Manage Applications >>> I had to click/tap on the app then it gave me options to uninstall, force stop, clear cache/data. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

ADB lets you uninstall applications. Just go:

```
adb uninstall <package>
```

You can find ADB in the tools folder of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 19):

In AndroidStudio (at least in v0.9.9) you can wipe data from a AVM. Go to Tools - Android - AVD Manager and in the menu for an AVM select "wipe data".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two solution:

1. When the emulator not running go to Tools -> AVD Manager -> in actions section click wipe data -> OK[image]
2. In emulator go to setting and then select app then delete.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Android emulator,

- Visit the **Settings** widget on the Home screen. (Not the settings you may visit through more button (three-dotted button))
- Then click **Apps and notifications**.
- After that click **See all apps** that you can see on the top half of the screen.
- Select the app you are supposed to delete.
- Then click the Uninstall.

Yes. You did it!!! Now your app is uninstalled from the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

1). go to settings in emulator
2). go to storage use
3). click on your application.
4). select uninstall

regards
Dharma

Answer (score 0):

Before starting emulator check on wipe user data

Answer (score 0):

**In the Android emulator**,

1. Visit the Settings widget on the Home screen.
2. Then click Apps and notifications.
3. After that click See all apps that you can see on the top half of the screen.
   Select the app you are supposed to delete.
4. Then click the Uninstall.