# Access Denied Error while loading a local HTML file in the webview

Tags: android, webview, android-11

I am trying to view a HTML file, which is stored in my app directory according to scopped storage, The exact HTML file url is `"file:///data/user/0/my.app.package/files/Download/page_1.html"`
However, I am getting open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) error. Where I can see manually that the file exist at that path. My target sdk version is 30, Android 11 and I can't change it I need it working on android 11. How can I fix it?

What I have already tried

1. Added the following code to the manifest file

   android:supportsRtl="true"

   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
2. I am using webviewAssetLoader for the file loading ( working fine with html file from the assets ) but not with file from the app internal storage

Comment: What have you tried to fix the problem yourself? If I google "android webview access denied" there are many StackOverflow questions related to that problem. Maybe this one would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131662/1306012

Comment: @BrunoBieri Thanks for the comment, however I already did try all the fixes mentioned in the question you tagged. Nothing working. Its due to some policy change in the android-11 API level 30

Comment: I see. Then I would highly recommend to update your question with "all the fixes" you've tried already to rule out possible problems. Further I would link the "policy change" you mentioned for Android 11 to further understand that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am going to mention the fixes I did try.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the below code.

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but the error I was getting was "access denied".  In the original post Ray says he's getting an "ENOENT (No such file or directory) error" message.  The title of this post "Access denied".  Technically speaking those should mean different types of errors.  This solution definitely worked for the case of "access denied". No such file or directory would seem to indicate that the requested page does not exist at the location specified in the file URL. Ray should debug and use the "Device File Explorer" to see if the file actually exists if this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a few weeks ago, you need to change the way to access the HTML file.

You should use the WebViewAssetLoader.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped to dig more into the WebViewAssetLoader. Now I am using the WebViewAssetLoad as well for viewing the HTML file, but unfortunately now I am getting open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) error. Where I can see manually that the file exist at that path.

Comment: @Ray you could update your question accordingly so other people which try to help you see what you already did.

Answer (score 0):

```
binding.webView.apply {
        visible()
        settings.apply {
            useWideViewPort = true
            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            builtInZoomControls = true
            displayZoomControls = false
            allowFileAccess = false
            allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = false
            allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = false
            allowContentAccess = true
        }
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this@YourActivity,
            "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider",
            File(yourHtmlFilePath!!)
        )
        webViewClient = MyWebClient(this@YourActivity)

        contentUri?.let { loadUrl(contentUri.toString()) }
    }
```

and `MyWebClient` class is

```
class MyWebClient(context: Context) : WebViewClientCompat() {
private val assetLoader: WebViewAssetLoader = WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
    .addPathHandler(
        "/public/", WebViewAssetLoader.InternalStoragePathHandler(
            context,
            File(context.filesDir, "public")
        )
    )
    .build()

override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
    view: WebView,
    request: WebResourceRequest
): WebResourceResponse? {
    return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.url)
}

override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
    return if (request.isForMainFrame) {
        view.context.startActivity(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.url)
        )
        true
    } else false
}
```

}