# image picker is not asking for permission flutter 2022 android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, imagepicker

I am encountering a problem with the `image picker` its not asking for permission every time I try to access the gallery. I have SDK 33 API   Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable Dart SDK version: 2.17.6 I tried to run flutter clean but still the same. the only thing I see in the android manifest is this `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"`.

Answer (score 1):

Image picker doest need those permissions now

> It is no longer required to add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" as an attribute to the  tag in AndroidManifest.xml, as image_picker has been updated to make use of scoped storage

You can get the info from the read me section of image picker

Comment: yes I also read about that what I mean is everytime I run the app and click the gallery it suupose to ask for permission but its not showing any box its just opens the gallery.

Comment: Not everytime. Only once or till it's allowed

Comment: how can I make it ask for permission everytime I open the gallery since plugin will automatically do it , i am not sure if I accept it once since I dont see anything

Comment: You don't have to ask permission everytime. Only till it's allowed. You can go to settings -> apps -> your app -> permission -> remove the permission and run the app again. It should ask the permission again

Comment: settings in the android studio? i dont see the apps there. sorry still newbie

Comment: In your phone settings not Android studio sorry

Comment: I only use emulator , I tried to check it before it doesnt have any setting

Comment: Delete the app from emulator and reinstall again

Comment: sorry i dont follow you, how am I going to do that? what I built is just a gallery button only . what i have in my emulator is gallery, camera, and contact only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994407/how-do-i-delete-sample-app-from-an-android-emulator